# Invalid view. Send email - Laravel - 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send an email with Laravel. I have a view in folder: `views/emails/user.blade.php` with simple HTML.

I have created Mailable: `php artisan make:mail UserEmail`. In my Controller where I am sending email:

```
Mail::send($request->user())
    ->queue(new PropertyAsk());
```

Mailable:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('some email')
                ->view('emails.user');
}
```

, but when I try it says:

> ```
> "message": "Invalid view.",
> "exception": "InvalidArgumentException",
> "file": "...vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php",
> "line": 310,
> ```

I am sure that I have that view. I can return it with some method controller.

Answer (score 1):

The `send` method is expecting a mailable.

```
/**
 * Send a new message using a view.
 *
 * @param  string|array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable  $view
 * @param  array  $data
 * @param  \Closure|string  $callback
 * @return void
 */
public function send($view, array $data = [], $callback = null)
```

However, you are passing it an instance of `App\User`. You can change it like this:

```
Mail::to($request->user())
    ->send(new UserEmail)
    ->queue(new PropertyAsk);
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#sending-mail